# jQuery UI: Acceder a elementos de una lista sortable()

Tags: html, jquery-ui

Estoy empezando a trastear con jQuery UI para ordenar los elementos de una lista de canciones; veo que `.sortable()` actúa sobre la lista en sí, no sobre sus elementos, pero si quiero acceder exactamente al elemento que estoy clicando, ¿cómo lo puedo hacer?

La lista es la siguiente:

```
<div class="ordenar">

    <form class="cancion-lista row d-flex" method="post" action="<?=url_base?>recopilatorios/indice" data-id-cancion="<?=$id_cancion?>"> <!--Bloque con cada una de las canciones de cada lista-->

        <span class="numero-decada" style="transform: translateY(-2px);"><?=$orden?></span> <!--Puesto en el recopilatorio-->

        <span class="cancion-autor-ano puntos pl-3"> <!--Información de la canción-->
            <span class="font-italic"><?=$titulo_cancion?></span>
            <span> de </span>
            <span class="font-weight-bold"><?=$nombre_autor?></span>
            <span>(<button class="boton-enlace" role="link" name="recopilatorio" value="<?=$recopilatorio?>"><?=$ano?></button>)</span>
        </span>

        <span class="ml-auto"> <!--Reproductor de sonido-->
            <span class="enlace-youtube" data-video="<?=$id_youtube?>"></span>
            <span class="caja-youtube"></span>
        </span>

        <span class="boton-x align-self-center">x</span> <!--Botón para eliminar las canciones-->

    </form>

    ...

</div>
```

El `form` se puede repetir entre 1 y 15 veces dentro de un bucle PHP.

Su aspecto, para, por ejemplo, seis elementos `form` es el siguiente (el título y subtítulo de la lista y los botones quedan fuera del `div` para evitar que se puedan ordenar):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y, por ejemplo, este script:

```
$(function()
{
    $('.ordenar').sortable(
    {
        update: function()
        {
            var hijos = $(this).children();
            console.log(hijos);
        }
    });

    $('.ordenar').disableSelection();
});
```

Cuando terminas de arrastrar un elemento de la lista, un `form`, te imprime por pantalla un array con todos los `form`, porque `this`, claro, hace referencia al `div` con `class="ordenar"`, pero ¿si quisiera que imprimiese el `<?=$orden?>` del `form` en concreto que acabo de manipular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El segundo parámetro del evento contiene el elemento arrastrado, la nueva posición la obtienes con `index()`.

```
    $('.ordenar').sortable(
    {
        update: function(event, ui)
        {
            console.log(ui.item.attr('data-id-cancion')+" en "+ui.item.index());
        }
    });
```

Comment: ¿`item` hace también referencia al elemento?

Comment: Al elemento arrastrado.

Comment: Me refiero a que si para acceder al elemento necesitas tanto `ui` como `item`.

Comment: Es correcto. [Documentación](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update).